# Can't add entry to repository

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, postgresql

I've got a db and ET DBModel. I use PostgreSQL.

When I'm trying to add an entry to my grid nothing happens. But Delete and Edit Works fine.
What should I do?

Thanks.

**Here's the Controller Code**

```
 public ActionResult GetFormForAddOrEdit(string id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            return PartialView(new TypeDictModel());
        }
        else
        {
            TypeDict td = typeDictRepo.GetById(id);
            TypeDictModel tdt = new TypeDictModel() { Oid = td.Oid, FormOfProduction = td.FormOfProduction };
            return PartialView(tdt);
        }
    }


    public virtual string SaveTypeDictEntry(TypeDictModel tdm)
    {
        string newTDE = typeDictRepo.Save(tdm.Oid, tdm.FormOfProduction);
        return newTDE;
    }


    public virtual void DeleteEntry(string id)
    {
        typeDictRepo.Delete(id);
    }
```

**And here's the view**

```
    function CloseTypeDictModal() {
    $('#EditTypeDictModal_Close').click();
}

function SaveNewEntry() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveTypeDictEntry", "TypeDict")',
        async: true,
        dataType: "html",
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#TypeDictForm').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {

            CloseTypeDictModal();
            $('#newTypeDictGrid').jqGrid().trigger("reloadGrid");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what is your Save method doing inside the repositary ? did you use breakpoints to see what happens ?

Comment: Could you define *not works*? What is the expected and what is the actual outcome?

Comment: http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/8576/qweqwec.png Here's what I have

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my repositorys. Missed this line Context.SaveChanges();  ^^